# Button to the bottom but dynamic

Tags: html, css

Hellos,

I've tried a lot and I've viewed any site which I found by searching but couldn't solve my problem

I want to have a button, centered and it have to stay on the bottom with fixed space from it. So that it's always on the same place at any page.
That's not the problem.

BUT when I have a site now with more text than screensize; a site with scrollbar; the button is not at the real bottom, it stays at the current screen bottom when the page got loaded and also over the text.

How can I solve this?

my code is in the moment:

```
HTML:
<a href='departments.php'><img src='images/backwf.png' class='button'></a>

CSS:
.button {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
position: absolute;
margin-right: 50%;
margin-left: 50%;
bottom: 20px;
}
```

I've created a jsfiddle to show exactly what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/t5c6pspd/

Comment: You want a button at the end of the screen. But when the content is longer than the screen, the button should at the end of content, right?

Comment: Hi Duannx,

yep, right. Always at the same position at the bottom but when the content is longer that button should be also still on the real bottom but not infront/behind the text.
to show this as I meant it i've created that jsfiddle.

Comment: See that [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t5c6pspd/2/). Is it as expect?

Comment: that looks great. I've added some more "test breaklines" to get more content but at the moment it really looks exactly for what I was searching for... I'll add that code snippets to my page and let you know if it is completly working asap.

Comment: I added my answer with explain below. If it works, please accept it.

Comment: hey again,
I had some problems as the button didn't was at the same position and I didn't knew why.. I just knew it must be at my side as it was working at jfiddle, and yea, I missed some top-margin at my other tables in css... after removing it, it's working perfectly now.

thanks a lot for your help and support. I've marked it as solved answer and +1

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your content a fixed `min-height`, so the button will stay at the bottom when the content is short. When the content is longer than screen the button will stay under the content.
To center the button, give it `display:block` and `margin: 20px auto`

```css
.content {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  width: 100%;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
}

button {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  This is test text <br> This is test text <br> This is test text <br> This is test text <br> This is test text <br>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <button>Test</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `position: fixed`.

Comment: that I also tested, but the problem is that the button is over the text when scroll down and is even on the text at the bottom

Comment: Try `position: static`. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="canvas"></div>
<div id="button"></div>
#canvas{
    border:1px solid black;
    position:relative;
        display:table;      
        top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-top: -320px;
}
#button{
   position:absolute; 
   margin-left:auto;

   width:150px;
   bottom:280px;
}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
button{
  width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 5%;
 margin-left: 40%;
margin-right: 40%


}
```

```html
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test<br>


<button>test</button>
```

Comment: that I also tested, but the problem is that the button is over the text when scroll down and is even on the text at the bottom