# Footer on site doesn't stay on the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css, sass

When the page is loaded the footer does not appear in the correct location. It seems to load at the bottom of the browser(I want it to go past the bottom of the browser to bottom of page if to much content on page) but then when you scroll to see the rest of the content it stays in the same place on the page which is covering content(doesn't stay on bottom of browser). I've set `position: absolute;` and `bottom: 0;` but these don't to seem to work as intended.

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Projects</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav class="row">
        <a class="mobileNav"></a>
        <ul class="col offset-desktop-7 desktop-5 offset-tablet-6 tablet-6 mobile-12">
          <li class="col desktop-4 tablet-4"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li class="col desktop-4 tablet-4"><a href="portfolio.html">Projects</a></li>
          <li class="col desktop-4 tablet-4"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <section class="col desktop-12 tablet-12 mobile-12">
        <h1>Lewis Blundell</h1>
        <h2>Junior Web Developer</h2>
        <h3>HTML5 | CSS3 | JavaScript | PHP | MYSQL</h3>
      </section>
    </header>
    <section class="wrapper">
      <h1 class="col desktop-12 tablet-12 mobile-12">Projects</h1>
      <article class="row">
        <aside class="col desktop-3">
          <img src="Images/placeHolder.png" alt="">
          <img src="Images/placeHolder.png" alt="">
          <img src="Images/placeHolder.png" alt="">
        </aside>
        <div class="col desktop-6">
          <p>hello</p>
        </div>
        <aside class="col desktop-3">
          <img src="Images/placeHolder.png" alt="">
          <img src="Images/placeHolder.png" alt="">
          <img src="Images/placeHolder.png" alt="">
        </aside>
      </article>
    </section>
    <footer class="row">
      <p class="col desktop-12 tablet-12 mobile-12"> Lewis Blundell &copy 2017</p>
    </footer>
  </body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="Script/script.js"></script>
</html>
```

SASS:

```
/* --- Variables --- */
$columnAmount : 12; /* This is used to set the amount of columns that will be used for a responsive grid layout */
$green : #3E9633; /* Main green background colour used throughout site */
$white : #FFFFFF;
$grey : #444444;


/* --- General Styling --- */
aside{
  img{
    width: 75%;
    margin-botom: 20px;
  }
}
html{
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper{
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom:40px;
}
body{
  padding-bottom:50px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: $grey;
  color: $white;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  h1{
    text-align: center;
    color: $white;
    font-size: 3rem;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
}
header{
  color: $white;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: $green;
  nav{
    .mobileNav{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background: url(../Images/burger.png) no-repeat 98% center;
    cursor:pointer;
    }
    overflow:hidden;
    ul{
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      li{
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 150%;
        &:hover{
          background-color: $grey;
        }
        a{
          color: $white;
          text-decoration: none;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  h1{
    font-size: 5rem;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  h2{
    font-size: 3rem;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
  h3{
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
footer{
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  bottom: 0;
  width:100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: $green;
}
/* --- Media Queries and General Layout--- */

.row{
  clear:both;
  width:100%;
}

.col{
  display:block;
  float:left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-height:auto;
 }

@media screen and (max-width:480px){ /* Styling for mobile viewports */
  @for $i from 1 through $columnAmount{
    .mobile-#{$i}{
      width: 100% / $columnAmount * $i;
    }
    .offset-mobile-#{$i}{
       margin-left: 100% / $columnAmount * $i;
    }
  }
  header{
    nav{
      ul{
        background-color: $grey;
        height: 0;
        li{
          float:none;
          text-align: left;
          width: 100%;
          margin: 0;
          a{
            padding: 10px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid $white;
            display: block;
            margin: 0;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  header nav ul.open{
    height: auto;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:481px) and (max-width:800px){ /* Styling for tablet viewports */
  @for $i from 1 through $columnAmount{
    .tablet-#{$i}{
      width: 100% / $columnAmount * $i;
    }
    .offset-tablet-#{$i}{
      margin-left: 100% / $columnAmount * $i;
    }
  }
  header nav a.mobileNav{
    display:none;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:801px){ /* Styling for desktop viewports */
  @for $i from 1 through $columnAmount{
    .desktop-#{$i}{
      width: 100% / $columnAmount * $i;
    }
    .offset-desktop-#{$i}{
      margin-left: 100% / $columnAmount * $i;
    }
  }
  header nav a.mobileNav{
    display:none;
  }
}
```

Images used in site:

[image: Placeholder image]

[image: BurgerMenu]

Comment: If you want to make footer always visible at bottom irrespective of scroll action, then you have to use "position:fixed".

Comment: That is what I'm trying to avoid, I want the footer to be pushed to the bottom of the page not the browser. If there is a small amount of content then I want it pushed to the bottom of the viewport but if there is a large amount i want it to go after all of the content.

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44797962/4254681) in this post. Is that what you need?

Answer (score 4):

try fixed position

```
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
```

if you want to be at bottom of browser page if your content height is less than window browser and if is more it be at the bottom of content you can try this

```
body{
  position: relative;
}
footer{
  bottom:0;
}
```

and use this javascript code for that

```
$(document).resize(function() {
    var bh = $("body").height();
    browser_height = window.innerHeight;
    if(bh<browser_height)
      $("footer").css("position","fixed");
    else
      $("footer").css("position","absloute");
})
```

Comment: That is what I'm trying to avoid, I want the footer to be pushed to the bottom of the page not the browser. If there is a small amount of content then I want it pushed to the bottom of the viewport but if there is a large amount i want it to go after all of the content.

Comment: as what I get from your comment I updated my answer.you can check it out and if its not what you mean please tell me

Comment: Still no luck, if the total height of the page is bigger than the browser I want the footer to the bottom of the page after the content. This means that it would not be visible until you scroll to the end of the page.

Comment: I considered it.if the total high of the page is bigger than the browser then footer will be after the content because the position will be absolute.you can see demo here https://codepen.io/poursadeqi/pen/jwxmax

Comment: This is what I am trying to achieve, but for some reason it doesn't work with my page?

Comment: I have used jQuery.have you loaded it? in the console of google chrome dev don't have any error?

Comment: yes I have loaded jQuery, I already use that for some js. There is also no errors being shown. It is also using the footer as though it is fixed to the bottom of the browser.

Comment: In the below of page of the link I got you demo mode its option for export and you can export and see it.you have to add this js at the end of your codes.did you do the same?

Comment: and I also used this link for jQuery library https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: I've add the code from the js file but it is still not doing what I need it to do, it is still only making the footer stick to the bottom of the browser. I also added a console.log() to output the values of bh and browser_height just to be sure and the body height is less than the browser_height which is strange since you still have to scroll the page?

Comment: you can compare your code with this file:https://codepen.io/poursadeqi/share/zip/jwxmax/

Comment: Pretty much the exact same, I'm getting the feeling there must be conflicting CSS styling that may be causing the issue?

Comment: yes maybe,you can test conflict css by changing css to body{
  position: relative !important;
}
footer{
  bottom:0 !important;
}

Comment: does in the zip file that I gave to you works correctly?

Comment: I got rid of anything that made the footers positioning absolute or fixed, it now goes below the content but if the page has a small amount of content it goes at the end which is half way up the page

Comment: I changed to apply this code on resize body.you can check it out that this does this fix your problem.the last code had this bug that on resize did'nt update position of footer

Comment: doesn't seem to be making any difference on the pages with a smaller amount of content even though they have the same layout and structure.

Comment: as in old version when page resized position didn't change, it didn't work correctly but when the size of page update footer position update too.this must work correctly.you can try it

Comment: not sure whats going on because if the content is less than the size of the browser the footer does not go to the bottom of the browser which is what I need it to do. But if the content if larger than the browser the footer will go to the bottom of the content which it does

Comment: on what browser and operation system your are testing cause I tested it on chrome on mac it's ok even when the content is less than browser height

Comment: Chrome on Kubuntu

Comment: Started the project from scratch with less styling but still getting the same issue and the js code you have given doesn't seem to make any changes

Comment: the codes in question are the exact code that you have?